# Is there a camera system for cars that can record the front, rear, and inside of the car at the same time?

Tags: car, security, camera, backup-camera

I am looking for a camera security system that would provide a dashcam but also be able to:

- record what is happening behind my car (like a backup camera, except this one would record while I am driving forward).
- record the interior (backseat) of a car.
- record the audio inside the car.
- store the last 10-30 minutes of video, sort of like a black box.

This is because I was planning on starting to drive for uber or lyft and thought that cameras would be good for safety (both mine and the customers, e.g. if we are rear-ended).

I would think that something like this would already exist in limos (or other cars used by paranoid rich folks). Would it be possible to have something like this installed e.g. by some customization shop, or would this be "too custom" (because of the hardware requirements)?

Comment: I voted to close this because you are seeking shopping assistance. I will say, though, some [Google-Fu](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&site=&source=hp&q=vehicle+camera+systems&oq=vehicle+camera+systems&gs_l=hp.3..0l3j0i22i30l7.1638.8559.0.8842.23.17.0.4.4.0.909.2565.11j2j1j0j1j0j1.16.0.msedr...0...1c.1.62.hp..3.20.2615.0.gVEIXHD6ig8) may be of some assistance.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not about repairing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoPro has a multicamera configuration where you can align the time and merge all of the feeds into a multi screen single interface feed.  They store the video centrally in a wifi enabled storage device using 802.11g

Most of the commercial solutions are cost prohibitive.